# for loop that compares two arrays always returns false

Tags: javascript, for-loop

As part of a coding challenge I am creating a function that compares two arrays, and returns 'true' whenever at least 1 value in Array1 exceeds its corresponding value in Array2, and otherwise return false.

Therefore, `const a = isFirstSuperior([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3])` is supposed to resolve to 'true' because of the last digit in each of the arrays (4 is indeed greater than 3.

The source of my confusion is as follows:

1. Why does my solution (below) always resolve the above expression to 'false'; and
2. Given that the actual solution has the "return false" statement completely outside of the 'for loop', why doesn't their code automatically resolve to 'false' every time? How does it know to respect the fact that the 'for loop' returned 'true' in this case and skip to the end of the function without returning 'false'?

**My (unsuccessful) solution**:

```
function isFirstSuperior(arr1, arr2) {
    for (i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
      }
}
```

**The actual solution**:

```
function isFirstSuperior(arr1, arr2) {
    for (i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]) {
                return true
            } 
     }
    return false
}
```

Comment: `else { return` that kills the function. Also see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable-loop

Comment: yep! if the elements are equal (arr1[0] and arr2[0] for instance), then your function will return `false`...so you should not return in that case

Answer (score 1):

The working solution will only return false if the whole loop completes.

Otherwise if the `return true` is executed the loop breaks and the function is exited and the `return false` statement is never reached.

Your version will not get past the first element in the array since you have a return for both conditions and either return breaks the loop and exits the function

Answer (score 0):

`return` means returning what after `return` and then finishing the function. So in the function I put `console.log` which shows the end of the function at `i`'s value. `i` shows 0 then it means the function is finished without other `i` values.

```
function noAfterReturn;() {
  console.log('before return');
  return;
  console.log('after return');
}

noAfterReturn();
//only shows 'before return'
```

When using `for` loop `return` finishes the loop.

```js
function isFirstSuperior(arr1, arr2) {
    for (i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]) {
                return true
            } else {
                console.log(i);
                return false
            }
      }
}

const a = isFirstSuperior([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3])

console.log(a);
```